# How to make less paginate only when the input is larger than the screen size?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, less-unix

If I want to clear the screen and run less if the output of a program exceeds the number of lines on a screen, I can do something like:

```
mypgm | tee mypgm.out
LEN=$(wc -l mypgm.out | cut -f1 -d' ')
[[ $LEN >= $LINES ]]; then
   clear
   less -R mypgm.out
fi
```

It works just fine as long as none of the lines in the output wrap around, visually taking up more than a single line on the screen.
Is there an simple way to determine how many lines of the screen the output occupies visually, or do I have to loop over the output file, computing the number of "lines" a long line needs to display by using $COLUMNS

Comment: Just as an aside, you can save yourself having to do `cut -f1 -d' '`. Instead of doing `wc -l mypgm.out | cut -f1 -d' '`, you can do `wc -l <mypgm.out`, and `wc` will just print the number, eliminating the need to use `cut`.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't know about that, but in hindsight it makes sense since wc can't / doesn't print the filename of a pipe.  I'll be sure to use this in the future.

Comment: Also -- I just love it when someone helpfully marks a question as a duplicate but doesn't include a link to what they consider the original.  I looked for an answer before posting and didn't see it -- still don't.  So thanks @Inian for adding something useful to the post that actually points to an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you're actually looking for something like:

```
mycmd | less -F
```

From `man less`:

> `-F` or `--quit-if-one-screen`
>
> Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be displayed on the first screen.

You can make it a default behavior with:

```
export LESS='-F'
```

in your `.bashrc`.

The `-F` option is nicely combined with `-X` which will skip clearing of the screen before listing (can also have it as a default with `LESS='-FX'`).

Comment: Wow!  I can eliminate most of my script and just: mypgm | less -FX.  Thanks -- less code to maintain

Comment: Sadly -X appears to clear the screen sometimes when doing: `mypgm 2>&1 | less -RFX`  Maybe the -R is messing it up?

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce that, even when piping the ANSI sequence to clear the screen, e.g. `echo -e '\033[2J' | less -FRX`.

Comment: No Matter -- would have been perfect, expect I only want less to run when mypgm fails.  If $? is 0, I don't care about the output, so I still need some script to front end it, piping it through tee

Comment: You don't have to use `tee` (if you don't always need output on screen), just redirect the output to a file. Then check exit status and depending on that, call `less` on your output file.

Answer (score 0):

I found fold, which solves the problem:

```
fold -w "$COLUMNS" mypgm.out | wc -l
```

(no need for the 'cut' since wc is running against a pipe)